# How to find that particular array Item is present or not Using JQuery + Backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js

Each ArrayItem contains no. of Property like Id, Name, Description etc 
But we want to Fetch ArrayItem with Help of Name Property .

So Please give me code suggestion in Jquery or backbonejs without using for loop.

Comment: what do you want?  fetch data from sever side, or filter data from client side?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you are using `BackboneJS`, you already have [UnderscoreJS](http://underscorejs.org/) installed.  Underscore has several methods for searching through a collection.  For instance, using `_.findWhere(...)`:

```
var myArray = [ ... ];
var helpItem = _.findWhere(myArray, { name: 'help' });
```

This would return the first entry in the array that has a `name` property equal to `'help'`.  `_.findWhere(...)` can match multiple properties too.  If you want to find an item with something other than direct equality of properties, you can use `_.find(...)`:

```
var overTwentyOne = _.find(myArray, function(entry) {
    return entry.age > 21;
});
```

This would return the first entry in the array whose `age` property was greater than 21.

Note also that most of the list-centric methods in Underscore are automatically mixed into all `Backbone.Collection` instances.  So if you were searching through a Collection, the above `findWhere(...)` example could be more simply written as:

```
var helpItem = collection.findWhere({ name: 'help'});
```

This would return the first `Backbone.Model` instance from `collection` that had a property `name` equal to `help`.

Comment: sir thanks for ur suggestion